# How to convert QGIS generated tiff images into jpg/jpeg using GDAL command line utilities?

Tags: qgis, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I want to develop a web portal that will show the images dynamically produced by QGIS, but QGIS provided tiff images are too big in size and it is not possible to show it on website using image viewers. That's why I have decided to convert those tiff images into jpg/jpeg to reduce in size as well as browser friendly so that I can show those images on my website easily. But I don't know how to convert tiff images into jpg/jpeg using gdal commands.

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: two questions: 1) do you want only to change(convert) the image type from tiff to jpg or do you also want to resize? 2)which operating system do you use?

Comment: I also want to resize and I'm using ubuntu

Comment: If you have a WMS then the choice of format is determined by the the client, so a web client can request jpeg or png and a desktop GIS can select TIFF, and no need to convert yourself

Answer (score 36):

try this with gdal:

```
gdal_translate -of JPEG -scale -co worldfile=yes input.tiff output.jpg
```

it also create worldfile too...

i hope it helps you...

Comment: thanks to those who commented on my post. Aragon your solution worked for me

Comment: one more thing how can I do it dynamically so that I can show the image on the website

Comment: If you keep getting solid black output, you might need to specify the min and max values for scale. I used `gdalinfo` to get the min and max, then provide them like `... -scale 0 0.158 ...`

Comment: Good, but it discards any color information from the band rendering. Do you know how to keep it?

Comment: Legend @aragon! Thank you for this solution. Was using imagemagic's convert, but it's not lossless, so the resulting jpg was losing some detail. But this seems only get the jpg data out of the tiff file, no recompression going on as far as I can see.

Comment: Edit, just found `tiffsplit` it seems to also split the tif losslessly. (though this tool does it near instantly). Though the resulting files still appear to be .tif files.

Answer (score 14):

Hei!

Choose `Raster menu - Conversion - Translate (Convert format)`. Then choose `*Input file*` for the image You want to convert. Under the `*Output file*` You can choose the format You need. There is `.jpg` too (with some 20+ file types).

I got 40MB large .tiff file, after conversion its only 1,6 MB as .jpg.

Comment: Good, but it discards any color information from the band rendering. Do you know how to keep it?

Comment: I use as input float32 RGB image .tif file and when I store it as .jpeg is totally black.... Why I get that result?