# Load a raster file directly in Leaflet

Tags: raster, leaflet, geotiff-tiff, erdas-imagine

Is it possible to load a raster file (e.g. GeoTIFF or Erdas img) directly into a Leaflet map? If so, can you guide me to the correct documentation or method to do this?

I am trying to do this with the imageOverlay() function in Leaflet currently.

```
var imageUrl = 'http://localhost/test/my_raster.tif',
        imageBounds = [[30.430224, -87.193133], [30.435867, -87.185944]];
        L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
```

I am new to Leaflet.

Comment: Did you try converting it to jpeg?  Some say this works on the client side. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16311760/125400

Comment: I just converted it and it worked.  Thanks for the tip. I used the following [thread](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26249/how-to-convert-qgis-generated-tiff-images-into-jpg-jpeg-using-gdal-command-line) to see how to convert it with gdaltranslate. I am thinking that this isn't the best method for putting raster on a Leaflet map, but that I should rather be using a map or tiling service of some kind.

Comment: Just as a reference for future readers. For small rasters you can try another 'client-approach', using one of these Leaflet plugins: https://github.com/IHCantabria/Leaflet.CanvasLayer.Field or https://github.com/stuartmatthews/leaflet-geotiff

(disclaimer: I'm the author of the first one)

Answer (score 3):

Web browsers have support for [a limited list of image formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Image_types). They all support JPEG and PNG formats, and there's growing support for WebP.

Up to this date, no web browser supports TIFF images. Do not expect any of the other [raster file types](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/index.html) to be supported natively in any web browser.

The approaches to this problem are:

- Convert your raster data to either JPEG or PNG. This has the disadvantage of bigger file sizes (in bytes) and more work on preparing the data.
- Rely on browser plugins (such as [TIFF viewer for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tiff-viewer/)). This means any users would need to install that plugin in their browsers.
- Rely on Leaflet plugins such as [leaflet-geotiff](https://github.com/stuartmatthews/leaflet-geotiff) (or others in the [Leaflet plugins list](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#basemap-formats)). This means that javascript will run each time to decode the TIFF images.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the plugin georaster-layer-for-leaflet, it's so amazing.
https://github.com/GeoTIFF/georaster-layer-for-leaflet

Comment: This does not really answer the question.  It is always recommended to include a detailed answer rather than a link-only answer. Link-only answers are not good answers. It also smells like spam.