# TIFF to JPEG compress

Tags: qgis, gdal, geotiff-tiff, jpg

I have a GeoTIFF image, size 11gb. It's too big to work with. 
How can I compress it in JPEG format with QGIS? 
I tried through GDAL and did not succeed.

Comment: perhaps check this post regarding the correct GDAL usage: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26249/how-to-convert-qgis-generated-tiff-images-into-jpg-jpeg-using-gdal-command-line

Comment: I tried with this method and did not work in an 11GB file

Comment: TIFF can be compressed as well. Use this command `gdal_translate -of GTiff -co tiled=yes -co compress=JPEG -co photometric=YCBCR input.tif output.tif` and then create overviews with `gdaladdo -r average -ro --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG --config PHOTOMETRIC_OVERVIEW YCBCR 2 4 8 16 32 64`.

Comment: Please never just say *but it didn't work* or *did not succeed*, that will attract downvotes and close votes.  Instead, edit your question and say *what actually did happen*. Was there an application/software crash, was there an error message (if so what was the complete error message as text, not screenshot), did the program run but produce incorrect/unexpected results (if so what were they)?  And also, you need to edit your question and provide a `gdalinfo` or QGIS layer Properties->Information report for your TIFF, as currently we don't have enough informationto actually answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use BigTIFF in your operation.

BIGTIFF=YES

> gdal_translate -co BIGTIFF=YES -co compress=JPEG input.tif output.tif

it would help if you amended your quesiton to show us your GDAL script.

Answer (score 0):

A simply go to Raster/Conversion/Translate. Then in the Converted field go to "..." - Save to file, Choose: JPG or JP2

Comment: I tried with this method and did not work in an 11GB file

Comment: then you have other issues