# How to convert GeoTiff to PNG + World file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, convert, png

I have quite a big area with DTM as a GeoTIFF. I want to save it to PNG with world file, but how to do it just in QGIS?

- I know I can export view to PNG with world file, but it looses quality (Project/Export) .
- I know how to transform format from TIFF to PNG but there I can't find any option for world file creation...
- While i try to specify "PGW + yes" as extra option it says it is not supported...

What did I miss?

Comment: Can you use gdal_translate from the command line? (QGIS comes with gdal under the hood). I’m pretty sure there are options you can specify for world file creation etc.

Comment: Probably you have a reason to use PNG but big png is very inefficient GIS format because the file must be de-compressed completely when software does anything with it.

Answer (score 5):

Clearly do not know exactly how to proceed in QGIS but with GDAL command line utility gdal_translate, just need to do

```
gdal_translate -of PNG -scale -co "WORLDFILE=YES" input.tif output.png
```

It will write an `output.png` with an associated `output.wld` (contains world file content)

**Edit:** after answering, seen similar answer for jpeg e.g [How to convert QGIS generated tiff images into jpg/jpeg using GDAL command line utilities?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26249/how-to-convert-qgis-generated-tiff-images-into-jpg-jpeg-using-gdal-command-line/26252)

Answer (score 1):

Using the GUI, you can access the Translate tool:

Raster -> Conversion -> Translate

In this tool you can select the input layer, set the projection (optional), add other parameters (optional). Then select where you want to save the exported PNG image.

To export with a word file, add `-co WORLDFILE=YES` in the "Additional command-line parameters". You can check the final GDAL/OGR console call before running the tool.