# Export QGIS layout as georeferenced PNG image with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, png

I am using PyQGIS to export a map layout like this

```
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
settings = exporter.ImageExportSettings()
settings.dpi = 100
path = 'C:/data/test1.png'
exporter.exportToImage(path, settings)
```

If I save it as a tiff it is georeferenced but not when saving as a PNG.

Is there a way to export it as a georeferenced PNG, or would I need to add an extra step after the fact? E.g, using gdal translate with the exported tiff.

Comment: I'm not the greatest authority on raster formats so happy to be told I'm wrong but afaik, png can't store georeference information internally so, if you use gdal_translate to convert a geotiff to png, the srs and geo transform information will be written to the .aux xml file. What you could do is add `settings.generateWorldFile = True` to your script to write a world file for your png or export to pdf and use `settings = exporter.PdfExportSettings()` then `settings.writeGeoPdf = True`

Comment: @BenW png can't store it internally, but you can have a world file associated

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/398013/how-to-convert-geotiff-to-png-world-file-in-qgis may give hints

Comment: Unfortunately a world file has no SRS information included, as @BenW already mentioned. Why do you use PNG instead of TIFF anyway? TIFF format has much more compression options and allows overviews as well. There's only the web that requires JPG or PNG.

Comment: The software im exporting to can only use PNG. Im dealing with very large images, which is why I didn't want to add an extra step of converting the image to PNG

Comment: @Ben W using "settings.generateWorldFile = True", achieved what i was after. Thanks!