# Batch Georeference with GCPs in QGIS OR merge GCPs

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, georeferencing, batch, ground-control

Problem:

I have ~100 black PNG tiles that show nothing but prairie creeks (black-creeks tiles)

I have ~100 map PNG tiles with creeks and background map (map-creeks tiles) that I can use to georeference creeks in the black tiles (the tiles themselves do not line up perfectly, thus I must line up the creeks).

I have ~100 map TIFFs with no creeks that are already georeferenced (map-no-creeks tiles) that line up with the map-creeks tiles but NOT with the black-creeks tiles.

I want to load the GCP points from the map-no-creeks tiles to georeference the map-creeks tiles

then I can use the map-creeks tiles to georeference creeks in the black-creeks tiles.

I could do this one by one using georeferencer, but is their a way to load the file paths of the map-creeks tiles and map-no-creeks GCPs as a csv and do it in a batch?

Alternativly, could I merge all the map-creeks tiles, and merge all the map-no-creeks GCPs and then georeference the two merged products?

I am on a MAC using QGIS.

Comment: Do your map-no-creek tiles include *.wtf world files?  Are your map-no-creek and your map-creek tiles similarly named?  If so, you could use Python to create a new world file  rename to *pgw for each of the png files from the wtf fils.  That would automatically georeference the PNGs to the same location as the Tiffs.  If the black-creek tiles share the same extents you could do the same trick for them as well.

Comment: They do not, is there a way I can create *.wtf files for all of them at once?

Comment: Maybe, see here:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9421/creating-tfw-and-prj-files-for-folder-of-geotiff-files

Comment: Managed to create a map-creek.tfw file from one of the map-creek.tif using Raster Translate to convert format. I do not understand how to turn the map-creek.tfw into a file that qgis can recognize and use to georeference the corresponding map-no-creek.png

Comment: Problem solved! Used Gdal Translate to translate the map-no-creek.tifs into png and wld files which I could then rename to match the map-creek.png so qgis will automatically recognize them and assign them their proper place on the map  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/398013/how-to-convert-geotiff-to-png-world-file-in-qgis/398022#398022